# Bash: Replace array value with curl result

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a text file named `raw.txt` with something like the following:

```
T DOTTY CRONO 52/50 53/40 54/30 55/20 RESNO NETKI
U CYMON DENDU 51/50 52/40 53/30 54/20 DOGAL BEXET
V YQX KOBEV 50/50 51/40 52/30 53/20 MALOT GISTI
W VIXUN LOGSU 49/50 50/40 51/30 52/20 LIMRI XETBO
X YYT NOVEP 48/50 49/40 50/30 51/20 DINIM ELSOX
Y DOVEY 42/60 44/50 47/40 49/30 50/20 SOMAX ATSUR
Z SOORY 43/50 46/40 48/30 49/20 BEDRA NERTU
A DINIM 51/20 52/30 50/40 47/50 RONPO COLOR
B SOMAX 50/20 51/30 49/40 46/50 URTAK BANCS
C BEDRA 49/20 50/30 48/40 45/50 VODOR RAFIN
D ETIKI 48/15 48/20 49/30 47/40 44/50 BOBTU JAROM
E 46/40 43/50 42/60 DOVEY
F 45/40 42/50 41/60 JOBOC
G 43/40 41/50 40/60 SLATN
```

I'm reading it into an array:

```
while read line; do
    set $line
    IFS=' ' read -a array <<< "$line"
done < raw.txt
```

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of `[A-Z]{5}` with an `curl` result where the match of `[A-Z]{5}` is fed as a variable into the `curl` call.

First match to be replaced would be `DOTTY`. The call looks similar to `curl -s http://example.com/api_call/DOTTY` and the result is something like `-55.5833 50.6333` which should replace `DOTTY` in the array.

I was so far unable to correctly match the desired string and feed the match into curl.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

All the best,
Chris

EDIT:

**Solution**

Working solution based on @Kevin extensive answer and @Floris hint about a possible carriage return in the curl result. This was indeed the case. Thank you! Combined with some tinkering on my side I now got it to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    set $line
    IFS=' ' read -a array <<< "$line"
    i=0
    for str in ${array[@]}; do
        if [[ "$str" =~ [A-Z]{5} ]]; then
            curl_tmp=$(curl -s http://example.com/api_call/$str)
            # cut off line break
            curl=${curl_tmp/$'\r'}
            # insert at given index
            declare array[$i]="$curl"
        fi
        let i++
    done
    # write to file
    for index in "${array[@]}"; do
        echo $index 
    done >> $WORK_DIR/nats.txt
done < raw.txt
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the output? How complex is the curl request? Have you gotten anywhere with the bash script yet? In principle, "replace $a with $b" is a simple `sed 's/'$a'/'$b'/'` statement, so if you can get the values of "thing to replace" in `$a` and "output of curl" into `$b`, you're done. `$b=curl $options mysite?$a` might do it...

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't change anything about your script except add the matching part, since it seems that's what you're needing help on:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
        set $line
        IFS=' ' read -a array <<< "$line"
        for str in ${array[@]}; do
                if [[ "$str" =~ [A-Z]{5} ]]; then
                        echo curl "http://example.com/api_call/$str"
                fi
        done
done < raw.txt
```

EDIT:  added in the url example you provided with the variable in the URI.  You can do whatever you need with the fetched output by changing it to do_something "$(curl ...)"

EDIT2: Since you're wanting to maintain the bash array you create from each line, how about this:

I'm not great at bash when it comes to arrays, so I expect someone to call me out on it, but this should work.

I've left some echos there so you can see what it's doing.  The `shift` commands are to push the array index from the current location when the regex matches.  The tmp variable to hold your curl output could probably be improved, but this should get you started, I hope.

```
removed temporarily to avoid confusion
```

EDIT3:  Oops the above didn't actually work.  My mistake.  Let me try again here.

EDIT4:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
        set $line
        IFS=' ' read -a array <<< "$line"
        i=0
        # echo ${array[@]} below is just so you can see it before processing.  You can remove this
        echo "Array before processing: ${array[@]}"
        for str in ${array[@]}; do
                if [[ "$str" =~ [A-Z]{5} ]]; then
                        # replace the echo command below with your curl command
                        # ie - curl="$(curl http://example.com/api_call/$str)"
                        curl="$(echo 1234 -1234)"
                        if [[ "$flag" = "1" ]]; then
                                array=( ${adjustedArray[@]} )
                                push=$(( $push + 2 ));
                                let i++
                        else
                                push=1
                        fi
                        adjustedArray=( ${array[@]:0:$i} ${curl[@]} ${array[@]:$(( $i + $push)):${#array[@]}} )
                        #echo "DEBUG adjustedArray in loop: ${adjustedArray[@]}"
                        flag=1;
                fi
                let i++
        done
        unset flag
        echo "final: ${adjustedArray[@]}"
        # do further processing here
done < raw.txt
```

I know there's a smarter way to do this than the above, but we're getting into areas in bash where I'm not really suited to give advice.  The above should work, but I'm hoping someone can do better.

Hope it helps, anyway

ps - You should probably not use a shell script for this unless you really need to.  Perl, php, or python would make the code simple and readable

Comment: The output of the curl needs to be substituted into the input string in place of the match of `[A-Z]{5}`. There are multiple matches in each line, so you have to iterate over them...

Comment: @Floris I see now.  I missed that part.

Comment: @Kevin - Your example is quite close to what I'm trying to achieve – my problem now is how to replace the matched string in the array with the curled output?

Comment: @Chris did you check my other answer using just sed?

Answer (score 2):

Since I misread the first time:

How about just using sed?

```
sed "s/\([A-Z]\{5\}\)/$(echo curl http:\\/\\/example.com\\/api_call\\/\\1)/g" /tmp/raw.txt
```

Try that, then try removing the echo.  I'm not 100% on this since I can't run it on the real domain

EDIT:  And just so I'm clear, the echo is just there so you can see what it will do with the echo removed

Comment: the coordinates returned from `curl` are space separated which makes it difficult splitting the lines into an array further down the road.

Comment: Isn't that what you want though?  "the result is something like -55.5833 50.6333 which should replace DOTTY in the array."

Comment: So I guess you want to maintain an array for further manipulation?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to maintain the array. I just want to swap the value in the array where `[A-Z]{5}` matches. I'm under the impression that my English is not up to the task. My apologies.

Comment: This is actually a very nice answer, although apparently it doesn't quite give Chris what he wanted. I am going to mark it as "useful" nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

create a file `cmatch`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  echo $line
  a=`echo $line | egrep -o '\b[A-Z]{5}\b'`
  for v in $a
  do
   echo "doing curl to replace $v in $line"
   r=`curl -s http://example.com/api_call/$v`
   r1=`echo $r | xargs echo`
   line=`echo $line | sed 's/'$v'/'$r1'/'`
  done
done
```

then call it with

```
chmod 755 cmatch
./cmatch < inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

It will do what you asked

Notes:

- the `\b` before and after the `[A-Z]{5}` ensures that `ABCDEFG` (which is not a five letter word) will not match.
- using `egrep -o` produces an array of matches
- I loop over this array to allow the replacement of multiple matches in a line
- I update the line for each match found using the result of the `curl` call
- to keep code clean, I assign the result of the `curl` to an intermediate variable

**edit** Just saw the comments about arrays. I suggest to take the output of this script and convert it to an array if you want to do further manipulation...

**more edits** If your `curl` command returns a multi-line string (which would explain the error you see), you can use the new line I introduced in the script to remove the newlines (essentially stringing all the arguments together):

```
echo $r | xargs echo
```

calls `echo` with one line at a time as argument, and without the carriage returns. It's a fun way of getting rid of carriage returns.

Comment: Thank you for your script but something doesn't play along nicely: `$ ./label-replace.sh < raw.txt > output.txt
sed: 1: "s/DOTTY/-55.5833": unterminated substitute in regular expression`and this goes on for every match.

Comment: Could it be that your `curl` command doesn't return a single line but that it has a carriage return in it? That wasn't clear from your question but would explain the issue.

Comment: Did you ever try using my updated answer? I see that the speculation about carriage return was correct... The code edit I made after that actually took that into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash


while read line;do
  set -- $line
  echo "second parm is $2"
  echo "do your curl here"
 done < afile.txt
```

Comment: He does not want the second parameter. He wants the first parameter that matches `[A-Z]{5}`.

Comment: first parm is a single char , he needs to clarify his question

Comment: Upon rereading, I fail English too. He wants *all* parameters that match `[A-Z]{5}`, and states so clearly in the question. If his `curl` call reversed characters, the output for the first line should be `T YTTOD ONORC 52/50 53/40 54/30 55/20 ONSER IKTEN`, with parameters 2, 3, 8 and 9 replaced.

Comment: @Amadan - that's how I read the question as well. So there are two problems: loop over all the matches in turn; make the curl call; replace the string with the result of the curl. Repeat for all matches. Repeat for all lines.

Comment: @Floris and @Amadan – the two-digit-slash-two-digit params are geographic coordinates which need reformatting by removing the slash. I left the slash in there for easier splitting into an array. As I now have all the params separated, I can start replacing the `[A-Z]{5}` (those are Fix-Names) with their coordinates as returned by the URI mentioned above.